# About Sencha/Ext JS Events fire & on

Tags: javascript, android, events, extjs, sencha-touch

We're working on a web apps. To keep components pre-configured, I did a lot Ext.extend work.

Here is the pre-definitions.

In the entrance, in **index.js**

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
        var app = new App();
    }
});
```

The main class, in **App.js**, App will new some card components, such as:

```
App = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    initComponent: function(){
        this.sub1 = new Sub_Class_1();
        this.sub2 = new Sub_Class_2();
        this.sub3 = new Sub_Class_3();
        this.items = [this.sub1, this.sub2, this.sub3];
        App.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        this.sub1.on('Event1', this.Event1_fn, this)
    },
    Event1_fn: function() {
        //some codes
    }
});
```

The problem comes, in the definition of Sub_Class_1, in **Sub_Class_1.js**:

```
var firefun = function() {
    this.fireEvent('Event1');
};

Sub_Class_1 = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    //some similar init configure jobs.
    //add *firefun* into this class
})
```

The problem is, if I fire the event in firefun, there is no reaction from the program. Is there something wrong with the scope? Can the community help me with suggestions that I can use to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This is indeed due to the scope problem.

To solve it, I pass the eventName, eventListener, scope to the function. Let it can fire within the correct scope. Boom, it works!

Any better solution?